# Correct way for uploading image bytes to cloudinary

Tags: python, cloudinary

I am using http://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference as reference.

There are two cases in which I want to upload the files to cloudinary.

1. Upload image by directly giving url link.
2. Upload image bytes by taking them from different source.

I could solve case 1, but had trouble in 2nd. I am pasting my code flow below for reference.

```
import cloudinary
import cloudinary.uploader

from io import BytesIO
from StringIO import StringIO

def upload_image_to_cloudinary(img_tag):

  logging.debug("Uploading Image to cloudinary : %s"%img_tag)

  if 'src' not in img_tag.attrs:
    del img_tag
    return

  img_src = img_tag['src']

  if img_src.startswith('/blob'):

    quip_client = pgquip.get_client()
    blob_ids = img_src.split('/')
    blob_response = quip_client.get_blob(blob_ids[2], blob_ids[3])

    img_src_str = blob_response.read()  # this returns str object.
    # img_src = BytesIO(img_src_str)
    img_src = StringIO(img_src_str)

  cloudinary_response = cloudinary.uploader.upload_image(
    img_src,
    use_filename=True,
    folder="/pagalguy/articles",
    width=546,
    crop="limit"
  )

  img_tag['src'] = cloudinary_response.metadata.get("url")

  return img_tag
```

In case where `img_src` is a image blob `str` returned by another api, I passed it as `file` param mentioned in cloudinary doc in a very similar way as any external image url for eg: https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_400_400/AAEAAQAAAAAAAAIkAAAAJGRhNzJiYjY1LTUxOTctNDI4NC1hOGIwLWQ1OTVlNmZlZmVmYw.jpg

And, for checking how generic upload flows work like boto for s3, I check below repo code.
Refered https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/develop/boto/vendored/six.py#L633 this too.

Error Log:

> Invalid URL for upload
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/base/data/home/apps/s~pagalguy-staging/namita:v1.397698162588746989/articleslib/article_util.py", line 68, in upload_images_n_publish
>       tag = image_util.upload_image_to_cloudinary(tag)
>     File "/base/data/home/apps/s~pagalguy-staging/namita:v1.397698162588746989/api/image_util.py", line 133, in upload_image_to_cloudinary
>       crop="limit"
>     File "/base/data/home/apps/s~pagalguy-staging/namita:v1.397698162588746989/libs/cloudinary/uploader.py", line 23, in upload_image
>       result = upload(file, **options)
>     File "/base/data/home/apps/s~pagalguy-staging/namita:v1.397698162588746989/libs/cloudinary/uploader.py", line 17, in upload
>       return call_api("upload", params, file = file, **options)
>     File "/base/data/home/apps/s~pagalguy-staging/namita:v1.397698162588746989/libs/cloudinary/uploader.py", line 226, in call_api
>       raise Error(result["error"]["message"])
>   Error: Invalid URL for upload

Finally I don't know which is the correct way to upload image bytes to cloudinary.

Comment: for which definition of "does not work" ?

Comment: tried passing `StringIO.StringIO(img_src)` and `io.BytesIO(img_src)`, did not work. And I have tried `upload_image` as well as `upload` definition.!

Comment: For spelling out loud : FOR WHICH DEFINITION OF "DOES NOT WORK" ? "does not work" is the most useless possible description of a problem. If you hope to get any help, please describre what you expected and what happened exactly (with the full traceback if you got one etc).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Apologies for bad representation. I have edited the question, let me know anything else you want.

Comment: What does "blob_response.read()" looks like ? And have you tried replacing this with 1. an opened `file` object (with a local image file used for testing) and/or 2. a `StringIO` populated with the result of a `file.read()` call on the same file object as case 1 ? It looks like the problem is with your data, not with how you call the api.

Comment: Yes. Apparently, in google app engine, one can not use local file storage. So could not test it that way. Currently for now, I am uploading files to s3.

Comment: Nothing prevents you from doing api calls from your local workstation you know ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130455/discussion-between-namita-maharanwar-and-bruno-desthuilliers).

Answer (score 0):

Your `img_src` parameter, which represents `file`, should be populated with either a byte array buffer (`bytearray`) or a Base64 URI. You can try something like:

```
    with open(img_src_str, "rb") as imageFile:
      f = imageFile.read()
      img_src = bytearray(f)

    cloudinary_response = cloudinary.uploader.upload(
      img_src,
      ...
    )
```

Comment: 1. yes there is : https://github.com/cloudinary/pycloudinary/blob/master/cloudinary/uploader.py#L43
2. if the object passed is a file-like object (has a callable 'read' attribute) it's used as a file cf https://github.com/cloudinary/pycloudinary/blob/master/cloudinary/uploader.py#L234

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the `upload_iamge` method, totally missed it.

Answer (score 0):

That API can upload bytes, so if you are uploading `_io.BytesIO`, you may just use `.getvalue()` method to your bytesIO object like `uploader.upload(image_stream.getvalue(), public_id = filename)`