# upload image bytes to cloudinary upload API

Tags: aws-lambda, cloudinary

I am using cloudinary API to get different resolution of the image/video files.I am able to use upload API using following code and get the required resolutions from java code

Map uploadResult = cloudinary.uploader().upload(file, options);

Now i need to perform the same from aws lamda using java code since I need to get resolutions of content stored in s3 bucket. I can think of 2 possible ways of doing the same 1) point cloudinary to use s3 urls - this requires setup 2)byte array buffer or IO input stream. Is there any sample java code available to option 2 ?

I am referring to upload API here
https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#upload

This has some reference with python 
[Correct way for uploading image bytes to cloudinary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41098273/correct-way-for-uploading-image-bytes-to-cloudinary)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check this  example:

```
File file = new File("<image_path>");
byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
cloudinary.uploader().upload(fileContent, ObjectUtils.emptyMap()));
```

--Yakir